# Windows 10 and Filezilla upload issue

Tags: ftp, filezilla

For some reason, images that I upload to my website using FileZilla are not loading properly.

I have tried resolving the problem by clearing my cache, reuploading the images, checking my code to make sure that the images are being referenced properly, and opening port 21.

I have also contacted BlueHost, my web hosting provider, and asked them to look in to the matter.

----> Just an update:[code editor image page in Bluehost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Kqs.jpg)
The code appears correctly(in the HTML editor) for the pages and site that I need the pictures to show on. However, when I go to one of my images in the image folder and click on (code edit) I get this. Is there a button that should not be on which turns my pics to symbols or the language that appears here or something else? Not a good thing.Please let me know if you know anything at all that will help.

What could be the problem? I have used FileZilla in the past with no problem whatsoever.

data1 in Filezilla:
[data1 problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve70d.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39103/discussion-between-dawn-thomas-and-davidb).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are not transferring the images as ASCII files, as this will cause them to become corrupted during the transfer process. They must be transferred in binary format. To check your configuration for this in FileZilla, go to `Edit → Settings` and from the panel on the left side, choose `Transfers → File Types`. Make sure that the `Default transfer type` option is set to `Auto`.

Also make sure that the `Treat the following filetypes as ASCII files` list does not have the file extensions used by your images listed. If it does, remove them.

[image: FileZilla Settings Panel]

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I am working on getting rid of the data1 file

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 and then try.  Still the issue persists,  Click on your FileZilla icon in Windows 10 and set the compatibility mode to Windows 7 .